# TinyMCE truncating content after saving

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE is truncating regular(non formatted) text entered into fields. The content is being saved to .html files, which are pulled into iframes. The issue has been narrowed down to TinyMCE. Is there a default character limit in TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default character limit in TinyMCE.